# How to override text field with datetime picker to a field on Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, datetime

I need to override current text field with datetime field withing a plugin's frontend field in Wordpress. I need to format it the way where it's not possible to select days in the past - only today and in the future. I figured this below but it's not what I need as it's not showing hours selection and it's also possible to select any day(including days in the past). So I need to show hours option and to restrict date selection to today and 10 years the future.

```
add_filter( 'wcv_product_title', 'product_title_date' ); 
function product_title_date( $args ){ 
    $args[ 'class' ] = 'wcv-datepicker'; 
    return $args; 
}
```

(this goes to function.php)